# PAM auth doesn't look at the shadow attributes in LDAP

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap, pam, sssd

I have a sssd setup to authentication against an LDAP server. I would like to use shadow attributes so that if it's in the past or set to 0 it won't let the user authenticate. It let's the user authenticate as long as the password is correct, ignoring shadowExpire attribute.

Logs:

```
[sssd[be[default]]] [sdap_attrs_add_ldap_attr] (0x2000): Adding shadowLastChange [15033] to attributes of [tuser].
[sssd[be[default]]] [sdap_attrs_add_ldap_attr] (0x2000): Adding shadowMin [1] to attributes of [tuser].
[sssd[be[default]]] [sdap_attrs_add_ldap_attr] (0x2000): Adding shadowMax [90] to attributes of [tuser].
[sssd[be[default]]] [sdap_attrs_add_ldap_attr] (0x2000): Adding shadowWarning [7] to attributes of [tuser].
[sssd[be[default]]] [sdap_attrs_add_ldap_attr] (0x2000): Adding shadowInactive [30] to attributes of [tuser].
[sssd[be[default]]] [sdap_attrs_add_ldap_attr] (0x2000): Adding shadowExpire [15126] to attributes of [tuser].
[sssd[be[default]]] [sdap_attrs_add_ldap_attr] (0x2000): shadowFlag is not available for [tuser].
```

/etc/pam.d/system-auth

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

Additional Logs

```
[sssd[be[default]]] [find_password_expiration_attributes] (0x4000):Found shadow password expiration attributes.
[sssd[be[default]]] ([simple_bind_send] (0x0100): Executing simple bind as: uid=tuser,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
[sssd[be[default]]] ([simple_bind_send] (0x2000): ldap simple bind sent, msgid = 1
[sssd[be[default]]] ([sdap_process_result] (0x2000): Trace: sh[0x19b86b0], connected[1], ops[0x19daeb0], ldap[0x18389a0]
[sssd[be[default]]] ([sdap_process_message] (0x4000): Message type: [LDAP_RES_BIND]
[sssd[be[default]]] ([simple_bind_done] (0x2000): Server returned control [1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1].
[sssd[be[default]]] ([simple_bind_done] (0x1000): Password Policy Response: expire [-1] grace [-1] error [No error].
```

Comment: Do you have 'shadow:ldap' in nsswitch.conf?